# Which id is for Launchpad in Hot corners defaults?

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mountain-lion

Which id I use to hot corners defaults?

i.e.:
For Mission Control I use id 2

```
defaults write com.apple.dock wvous-bl-corner -int 2
defaults write com.apple.dock wvous-bl-modifier -int 0
```

Anyone knows which is for Launchpad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting my upper-left corner to Launchpad from System Preferences, then executing

```
defaults read com.apple.dock wvous-tl-corner
```

it appears you want the value 11 for Launchpad.